# Group phone numbers that correspond at the same url in the same row

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

in the database there are some equal rows where only changes the phone number. I would like to grouped into a single row phone numbers that correspond to the same url, in order to obtain the second table. I'd like to know if there was a way to do this in mysql with one or more queries, or by another method. Thanks in advance

```
Database1
    Url    |Company Name| Address |  City |ZipCode|PHONE
www.aaa.com|         AAA|StreetAAA|CityAAA|  00000|0000000000
www.aaa.com|         AAA|StreetAAA|CityAAA|  00000|1111111111
www.aaa.com|         AAA|StreetAAA|CityAAA|  00000|2222222222
www.bbb.com|         BBB|StreetBBB|CityBBB|  11111|3333333333
www.ccc.com|         CCC|StreetCCC|CityCCC|  22222|4444444444
www.ccc.com|         CCC|StreetCCC|CityCCC|  22222|5555555555
www.ccc.com|         CCC|StreetCCC|CityCCC|  22222|6666666666
www.ddd.com|         DDD|StreetDDD|CityDDD|  33333|7777777777
www.ddd.com|         DDD|StreetDDD|CityDDD|  33333|8888888888
www.eee.com|         EEE|StreetEEE|CityEEE|  44444|9999999999

Final Database to generate:
    Url    |Company Name| Address |  City |ZipCode|  PHONE1  |  PHONE2  |  PHONE3
www.aaa.com|         AAA|StreetAAA|CityAAA|  00000|0000000000|1111111111|2222222222
www.bbb.com|         BBB|StreetBBB|CityBBB|  11111|3333333333|          |
www.ccc.com|         CCC|StreetCCC|CityCCC|  22222|4444444444|5555555555|6666666666
www.ddd.com|         DDD|StreetDDD|CityDDD|  33333|7777777777|8888888888|
www.eee.com|         EEE|StreetEEE|CityEEE|  44444|9999999999|          |
```

Comment: This is doable with SQL if you have a maximum number of phone numbers you want to pull out (as per Gordon's answer). However, if you don't know the total number of numbers associated with one address, it's better to pull them all out and do this programmatically in a a script (which can iterate over all of them), or in a Spreadsheet application.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to put all the phones into a comma-delimited list:

```
select url, companyname, address, city, zipcode,
       group_concat(phone) as phones
from database1
group by url, companyname, address, city, zipcode;
```

However, this isn't exactly what you want.  The following comes closer and works if all groups have three phone numbers:

```
select url, companyname, address, city, zipcode,
       substring_index(group_concat(phone), ',', 1) as phone1,
       substring_index(substring_index(group_concat(phone), ',', 2), ',', -1) as phone2,
       substring_index(group_concat(phone), ',', -1) as phone3
from database1
group by url, companyname, address, city, zipcode;
```

So, the following fixes this:

```
select url, companyname, address, city, zipcode,
       (case when count(phone) >= 1
             then substring_index(group_concat(phone), ',', 1)
        end) as phone1,
       (case when count(phone) >= 2
             then substring_index(substring_index(group_concat(phone), ',', 2), ',', -1) 
        end) as phone2,
       (case when count(phone) >= 3
             then substring_index(group_concat(phone), ',', -1)
        end) as phone3
from database1
group by url, companyname, address, city, zipcode;
```

Comment: Hello, if I want also add phone4 and phone5, can you write the sql?

Comment: @Francesco . . . Just copy the line for "2" and replace it with "3" and "4".

Comment: If the number of phone numbers is subject to change, it's probably easier to use the first example with `group_concat()` and then split the result of that field in a scripting language (it's delimeted by `,` by default).